# Snapshot of a UIView composed of two UIView disappear when finish

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, snapshot

In my `UIViewController` i have some `UIView` added in it, and i want take a snapshot of a custom `UIView` composed of some of this `UIView`, and i do this:

```
UIView *tmp = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, first.frame.size.width, first.frame.size.height+second.frame.size.height)];

    [tmp addSubview:first];

    CGRect frame = second.frame;
    frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(first.frame);
    [second setFrame:frame];

    [tmp addSubview:second];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tmp.bounds.size, YES, 0.0f);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [tmp.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

EDIT add some more details:

```
UIView *first = self.myFirstView;
UIView *second = self.mySecondView;
```

`self.myFirstView` and `self.mySecondView` are UIView connected with Interface Builder:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *myFirstView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mySecondView;
```

the image is created perfectly, but when finish to create it, the `UIView` in the `UIViewController` just disappear, how i can solve the problem?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking. Can you show code on how you add the view?

Comment: Of course it disappears, that `tmp` view is not added in any superview so it's not rendered cause it probably gets released (ARC makes miracles :)) as soon as it goes out of the scope. Anyway, please show us how tmp is added into the view hierarchy.

Comment: tmp is created there as you can see in the code above, instead first and second UIView are connected as IBOutlet with a xib

Comment: i have added more details to my question

Comment: Try adding your `tmp` view to a superview (offscreen if you don't want the user to see it), and *then* create a snapshot. That should work. Also, any specific reason why you're suing `renderInContext:` and not `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` ?

Comment: no there isn't any reason, i have see some tutorial and answer on SO that use renderInContext, what's it's better?